# How do I get the number of days in a month for the specific date in that row of data using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if I have a data set including two columns, one which shows the month as a number and the other which shows the year (result of grouping my data using GROUP BY), I want to add another column called 'Days in the month' which will display the number of days in the respective month. Is there a way I can do this? Is there some function I can add in the SELECT clause?

I want to do this since there are further calculations I need to do with that number for each row.

Comment: Do you want to actually add a column to the table? Or just to the result set in a query?

Comment: what do you mean by result set in a query? I will eventually use this new column for calculations on my data set

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use:

```
select day(eomonth(datecol))
```

`eomonth()` gets the last day of the month.  `day()` just returns the day of the month -- the number of days in the month, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For older SQL Server versions, I use the following:

```
DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, date_column)- 1, -1))
```

Much less elegant than the previous answer, but functional.